# mySQL query find lowest "active" price in 24 hours

Tags: mysql

Please help me get rid of my headache..
In advance I apologize for my bad language, both in english and in mysql. Hopefully someone will understand the question.. :)

I've got a database where anyone can log prices for various products in various stores. The following query is an semi-theoretically example and might not work at all, but it is translated for illustrating my challenge.
The query is supposed to find the lowest registered price for a given $product in the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT img, chain.chainid, chain.chainname, shops.shopid, shoplocation, shopname, prices.price, DATE_FORMAT( price.timestamp, '%e. %M %Y, %H:%i' ) AS time
FROM shops
INNER JOIN prices ON shops.shopid = prices.shopid
INNER JOIN chain ON shop.chainid = chain.chainid
WHERE prices.product = '$product'
AND timestamp > SUBTIME( NOW( ) , '24:0:0.000000' )
ORDER BY price, timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

How can I make sure that I still find the lowest priced store even if the cheapest shop this morning has raised the price during the day (assuming I've got both prices in my table) and another shop is the cheapest now?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please [edit] it. Are you looking for the absolute lowest price in the time period? Or are you looking for the lowest current price? In other words, if a new record appears for the product, with a higher price in a given shop, should that record supersede an older one?

Comment: If it's indeed "*in the last 24 hour hours*"  - then your question does not make any sense.

Comment: You want a result from a table twice, once sorted purely by price, the other sorted by most current. The one result can exclude the other from your resultset. I'd do two selects and use `UNION`. Very good question, shame some people don't get it.

Comment: @PM77-1 You are selling something for $10 in the morning. In the evening, you set the price to $50. In the select/table, you occure **two times** within 24 hours and maybe you were cheaper than anyone else in the morning but you arent in the evening anymore. OP wants to figure out, how to make sure the most current price is still the lowest price. Legit question.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Yeah, gas prices for instance. If one seller increase his price, someone else could be cheaper at the time. I will try the rewritten query here soon and see if it works. But it looks like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewritten query:

```mysql
SELECT
  img,
  chain.chainid,
  chain.chainname,
  shops.shopid,
  shoplocation,
  shopname,
  prices.price,
  DATE_FORMAT(prices.timestamp, '%e. %M %Y, %H:%i') AS time
FROM shops
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT shopid, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM prices
    WHERE prices.product = '$product'
      AND timestamp > SUBTIME(NOW(), '24:0:0.000000')
             ) prices_tmp
    ON prices_tmp.shopid = shops.shopid
  INNER JOIN prices
    ON shops.shopid = prices.shopid
      AND prices.timestamp = prices_tmp.timestamp
  INNER JOIN chain
    ON shop.chainid = chain.chainid
WHERE prices.product = '$product'
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Pay attention to using `prices_tmp` subquery.
I'm not sure that it works though.

Some explanation: in the subquery for each shop latest price timestamp selected, `inner join` with `prices_tmp` filtrates old prices, then `order by` put the lowest price at the top.

Comment: The query runs without errors, but no rows returned. 
If I remove the subquery, keeps the subtime-line and switches the order to ASC it'll give me the absolute lowest price in the last 24 hours, unfiltered (as expected without the sub, ofcoarse). So, something is not quite right with the subquery i presume?